# Python App for Android Tablet

Tags: android, python

Is there an app for Android Tablets (I have the Toshiba THRiVE) that I can use to write and run Python? I have ConnectBot for remote access (mainly for C/C++), but I am curious if there is an app that I can write and run python without remote accessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at SL4A. There's even some books about it.

Comment: Be careful with this library because at work we were implementing an app with it and found a bug when displaying the Activity number 8. Then it always crashed. We tested it even loading the same "hello world" Activity 8 times and also crashed. Now I am coding it in Java without problems.